# Java Equivalent of IEnumerable<char>

Tags: c#, java, translation

This is the C# code that I have to convert:

```
static readonly IEnumerable<char> BigAlphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
static final Iterable<Character> BigAlphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
```

This gives me the error:

> incompatible types
>
> required: java.lang.Iterable
>
> found:    char[]

I know I'm getting this error because I'm trying to set an `Iterable<Character>` to a `char array` but I'm not sure what else can be done to translate it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do with it? In Java, an Iterable is not restartable so making it `static` is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the char[]? Iterate over it and read values from it? Write to it? Change its length? Random access? Match against a regex?

Comment: Well, it's a bit complicated and I'm absolutely new to C# but what I have in C# is this:

 `public static WildCardType GetWildCardType(char c) {
      switch (c) {
        case 'a':
          return WildCardType.LittleAlpha;
  }`

Comment: @PeterLawrey not restartable? An `Iterable<T>` just provides you an `Iterator<T>` e.g. for enhanced for loops.

Comment: Sorry I read it as Iterator. Using an Iterable could work, but I suspect it not a good idea. i.e. Using a String would be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple String work?

```
 static final String BigAlphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

String implements CharSequence, which seems to be what you need, and it also has loads of methods to check membership and such.

Comment: Perhaps but I need to do a direct translation so I'd also need the `toCharArray();` part. Wouldn't I?

Comment: Explain why you need to do a direct translation. See for example @Peter's comment why that may not be so great an idiom in Java.

Comment: I need to do a direct translation because a program that was done in C# is now wanted in Java by the customer.

Comment: IMHO, The best translation is to use a plain String.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final Iterable<Character> alphabet() {
  return new Iterable<Character>() {

    public final Iterator<Character> iterator() {
      return new Iterator<Character>() {

        private char cursor = 'A';

        public boolean hasNext() {
          return cursor <= 'Z';
        }

        public Character next() {
          return cursor++;
        }

        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot remove from stream");
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
for (final char ch : alphabet()) {
  /* ch in interval [A,Z] */
}
```

---

Here's a more generic form.

```
static final Iterable<Character> iterable(final CharSequence seq) {
  return new Iterable<Character>() {

    public final Iterator<Character> iterator() {
      return new Iterator<Character>() {

        private int cursor;

        public boolean hasNext() {
          return cursor < seq.length();
        }

        public Character next() {
          return seq.charAt(cursor++);
        }

        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot remove from stream");
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
/* ... */
for (final char ch : iterable("qwertyuiop")) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, have it your way... If you don't mind using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Iterable<Character> BigAlphas = Chars.asList("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray());
```